# Is there a way to get voice memo sync working with the iPod app in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, sync

Is there a way to get voice memo sync working with the iPod app in the iPhone.

Apple just recommends you turn voice memo syncing off.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: OS X(10.5.8)
iPhone 3GS - 3.0.1

Comment: What problem are you having? You left out the most important part of the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes supports syncing voice memos made only using the "Voice Memos" application.

[image]

These voice memos should sync automatically into your iTunes, under a playlist called "Voice Memos", but only if you have automatic syncing enabled for your device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not completely true you can use a variety of applications "speakEasy, voice memos, iTalk" to mention a few... the thing is with an iPod touch you need a headphone mic combo they sell them on the apple store of course. 
Hope this helps!